# Is there a program like searchmonkey/Everything that previews images or webms?

Tags: filesystems, search, journaling

> On Windows there a nice file search engine called Everything, which is >(unlike find) very fast and (unlike locate) always returns up to date results. AFAIK it works by filling a database from the NTFS journal (it doesn't work with other filesystems).
>
> I wonder if there's something similar (I don't care about the GUI; my point is the speed and the up-to-date guarantee) for Linux (ext3 or ext4); I have googled but found nothing. Can something like this be done or is even somebody working on it?
> ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31063/is-there-a-file-search-engine-like-everything-in-linux))

My question is whether such a tool exists that can preview images and webms (those that have been found, as a list of previews). Main use case is for imageboards.

Comment: Do you mean multiple [WebM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM) files with `webms`?

Comment: @Anthon: yes, plural is intended.