# A way to make virtual folders in Linux

Tags: linux, virtual-file-system

[Is there a file search engine like "Everything" in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31063/is-there-a-file-search-engine-like-everything-in-linux)
I came across this post from 9 years ago and I found there is something called Ferris.  It appears to be a VFS layer that runs on top of the existing file system.

The project has not had a new release in three-and-a-half years.

Is there anything with that feature list that is current? 
http://www.libferris.com/features

Comment: Have you tried it, to see if it still works on your system?

Comment: hm, within bounds, GNOME's `miners` implement that

Comment: can you give me a link to information about `miners`? I just find GNOME Mines when looking it up.  Is it part of GTK3? Also no, I have not yet tried Ferris.